# AWS Elastic Beanstalk is ignoring my Dockerrun.aws.json file

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I ran a couple of steps to get to a point where I have a pre-built docker image in AWS ECR. When I create a EB stack in AWS using the interface and uploading my `Dockerrun.aws.json` file, it creates the stack successfully.

Now I am attempting to create a stack via command line instead of the interface but I am bumping to an annoying issue which I am not sure how to resolve.

When running the following command:

```
$ eb create
```

Instead of it using the `Dockerrun.aws.json` where I provide the location it should pull the image from, it tries to build the docker image... In my folder where I run the command above I have the following files:

- Dockerfile
- Dockerrun.aws.json
- /src/ (my application)
- ebextensions

My assumption is that if I have `Dockerrun.aws.json` it should use it and ignore the Dockerfile?

Any clue what's going on?

Let me know if providing the content of the `Dockerrun.aws.json` or `config.yaml` will be helpful

Answer (score 4):

Per the Elastic Beanstalk documentation on [Single Docker apps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_image.html), if the CLI finds a Dockerfile in your directory it will use that over whatever is listed under the `Image` key in your Dockerrun.aws.json file.

My attempt to solve this issue is by creating `.ebignore` file, and add `Dockerfile` to be ignored by `eb cli` on the deployment

```
//.ebignore
Dockerfile
```

Comment: This was my problem, if a `Dockerfile` exists, the file `Dockerrun.aws.json` will simply be ignored by `eb create` and won't be zipped, so you will get the error `ERROR: No ecs task definition (or empty definition file) found in environment`

Answer (score 4):

I've just been fighting with similar issue for over an hour. The problem was with `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` file and lack of

```
deploy:
  artifact: Dockerrun.aws.json
```

inside. Each time you run `eb init` new config.yml will be created so remember to add the artifact line.